# Best way to create a .txt file on a server filesystem?

Tags: ajax, node.js, file, server

Im looking for the best way to alter or create a txt-file on a server filesystem after a client sided (web-app) interaction (similar to a log file). I was thinking about using AJAX. What would I need to edit a file on a Server through AJAX (or PHP).
And how about writing a file server with nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you simply use fopen? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'file content');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think basically you will have to define a particular route path on your server (Node.js), which you can request (POST is right) to with a client (AJAX) to create a file with the filename given with the request.

The server can then create a file once it gets the request.